# Why is lambda function not allowed here?

Tags: java, lambda, vaadin

I've been working arround a GUI in Vaadin, with some given classes from my IT chief. It's all great and that, but, today, I have encountered that I cannot use a lambda expression in a `addListener` method type. This method is custom, as the object that uses it. Here is the implementation:

```
public class ResetButtonForTextField extends AbstractExtension {
    private final List<ResetButtonClickListener> listeners 
        = new ArrayList<ResetButtonClickListener>();
    private void addResetButtonClickedListener
            (ResetButtonClickListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
    //Some other methods and the call of the listeners
}
public interface ResetButtonClickListener extends Serializable {
    public void resetButtonClicked();
}
```

To use this extension you must do this:

```
ResetButtonForTextField rb=ResetButtonForTextField.extend(button);
rb.addResetButtonClickedListener(new ResetButtonClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void resetButtonClicked() {
        //Do some stuff here
    }
});
```

If I use a lambda in `addResetButtonClickedListener` like this:

```
rb.addResetButtonClickedListener(ev -> {
    //Do some magic here
}
```

The compiler says that

> - Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method resetButtonClicked()
> - The method addResetButtonClickedListener(ResetButtonClickListener) in the type ResetButtonForTextField is not applicable for the arguments (( ev) -> {})

Even if I define lambda expression like this: `(ResetButtonClickListener ev) -> {}` still gives an error.

So question is, Why can't I use a lambda expression there? I'm missing something in the declaration of the code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The functional interface consists of the method

```
public void resetButtonClicked()
```

with no parameters. Your lambda tries to implement it with a parameter of type ResetButtonClickListener. What you want to do is

```
rb.addResetButtonClickedListener(() -> {
    // handling code goes here
});
```

Comment: Oh, I got acostummed to `ButtonClickListeners` of `Button` class, that take one event argument. I didn't think about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The reason of the error is clear in the msg

> The method addResetButtonClickedListener(ResetButtonClickListener) in the type ResetButtonForTextField is not applicable for the arguments (( ev) -> {})

so you can not use the lambda referring to a object **ev** because the method `resetButtonClicked` of the interface `ResetButtonClickListener` doesn't take any parameter...

do :

```
ResetButtonForTextField r = ....
r.addResetButtonClickedListener(() -> {
     //TODO
});
```